# Custom REST endpoints for a custom post type with custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, rest-api

I am working on a wordpress project that is highly customized. I have custom post type "foo-post" and within there I have a custom field "foo-field" (created by advanced custom fields plugin and is just a simple string).

Now I want to be able to query this "foo-Post" through the REST API. I have managed to include this custom post in API response, but the problem is that I want to filter the output based on "foo-field". Is it possible to create a route that can be called like this:

```
       /wp-json/v2/wp/foo-post?foo-field=something
```

If so, please help me figure out how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found my answer after diving into the WordPress's core code.
Yes, it is possible to do such a thing, all you need is to use the following function: 
register_rest_route

There are some tricky parts though. This function uses regular expressions and now I am going to figure out how to use that in this function.